# Proving differentiability at a point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $C^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n \backslash{0}$ such that $\bigtriangledown f(x)\rightarrow L$ as $x \rightarrow 0$, show that f is $C^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

I need to prove that $\bigtriangledown f(0)= L$ and from there its easy to see that f is $C^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, tried to manipulate the differentiation definition but somehow it seems that i can't find a formal way to show that 
$f(h)=f(0)+<L,h>+o(|h|)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the mean value theorem: $f(h) - f(0) = <\nabla f (\xi),h>$ so:
$$\frac{|f(h)-f(0)-<L,h>|}{|h|} = \frac{|<\nabla f(\xi) - L,h>|}{|h|}\leq \frac{|\nabla f(\xi) - L| \cdot |h|}{|h|} = |\nabla f(\xi) - L|$$
And since $\xi \in (0,h)$, the limit as $h \to 0$ equals 0 (since $\nabla f(x)\to L$), and by definition this means that the derivative at 0 is L.